# NLP Postagger can't grok imperatives?

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

Stanford NLP postagger claims imperative verbs added to recent version. I've inputted lots of text with abundant and obvious imperatives, but there seems to be no tag for them on output. Must one, after all, train it for this pos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special tag for imperatives, they are simply tagged as `VB`.

The info on the website refers to the fact that we added a bunch of manually annotated imperative sentences to our training data such that the POS tagger gets more of them right, i.e. tags the verb as `VB`.

Comment: I checked some of the imperatives you added and didn't see any nsubj-es (sentence subject). It may be useful in some cases. Although "Brian makes me a sandwich." has practically the same dependencies as "Brian, make me a sandwich!"