# Approach for identifying whether a sentence includes an imperative within it

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Looking to find out whether a sentence includes an imperative within it (e.g. categorize "click below" as an imperative, whereas "here is some information" as not).

Is this possible with e.g. the Stanford Parser? For reference, the main site (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) indicates 'Improved recognition of imperatives', however the dependency manual does not indicate a filed for them  http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf )

Alternatively, is there another approach which would work?

Comment: You are linking to the wrong part of the documentation; the grammatical mood of the verb is not a dependency relationship. However, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575795/nlp-postagger-cant-grok-imperatives

Answer (score 7):

I also failed to find any library or literature that (directly) addresses 'imperative detection' (there must be a different official name for it...). 
Here's what I've come up with by reading up on the grammar of imperatives, learning about [chunking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imPpT2Qo2sk) and some experimentation.

(Python + NLTK)

```
from nltk import RegexpParser
from nltk.tree import Tree

def is_imperative(tagged_sent):
    # if the sentence is not a question...
    if tagged_sent[-1][0] != "?":
        # catches simple imperatives, e.g. "Open the pod bay doors, HAL!"
        if tagged_sent[0][1] == "VB" or tagged_sent[0][1] == "MD":
            return True

        # catches imperative sentences starting with words like 'please', 'you',...
        # E.g. "Dave, stop.", "Just take a stress pill and think things over."
        else:
            chunk = get_chunks(tagged_sent)
            # check if the first chunk of the sentence is a VB-Phrase
            if type(chunk[0]) is Tree and chunk[0].label() == "VB-Phrase":
                return True

    # Questions can be imperatives too, let's check if this one is
    else:
        # check if sentence contains the word 'please'
        pls = len([w for w in tagged_sent if w[0].lower() == "please"]) > 0
        # catches requests disguised as questions
        # e.g. "Open the doors, HAL, please?"
        if pls and (tagged_sent[0][1] == "VB" or tagged_sent[0][1] == "MD"):
            return True

        chunk = get_chunks(tagged_sent)
        # catches imperatives ending with a Question tag
        # and starting with a verb in base form, e.g. "Stop it, will you?"
        elif type(chunk[-1]) is Tree and chunk[-1].label() == "Q-Tag":
            if (chunk[0][1] == "VB" or
                (type(chunk[0]) is Tree and chunk[0].label() == "VB-Phrase")):
                return True

    return False

# chunks the sentence into grammatical phrases based on its POS-tags
def get_chunks(tagged_sent):
    chunkgram = r"""VB-Phrase: {<DT><,>*<VB>}
                    VB-Phrase: {<RB><VB>}
                    VB-Phrase: {<UH><,>*<VB>}
                    VB-Phrase: {<UH><,><VBP>}
                    VB-Phrase: {<PRP><VB>}
                    VB-Phrase: {<NN.?>+<,>*<VB>}
                    Q-Tag: {<,><MD><RB>*<PRP><.>*}"""
    chunkparser = RegexpParser(chunkgram)
    return chunkparser.parse(tagged_sent)
```

Haven't tested the performance of the algorithm yet, though from my observations I'd say precision is probably better than recall. Note that the performance greatly depends on the correctness of the POS-tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will test your solution, and let you know

Comment: @M.Abulsoud how was your performance? I'm also trying to [parse Syntactic Trees with Imperatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56930193/6068675) and often they are tagged as Noun Phrase (NP).

Comment: @duichwer I'm sorry I couldn't find the result.